# Allow Community Users to Accept cases from a Queue

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities, queue

I have communities set up in my salesforce org and I would like to grant access to our Partners to Accept cases from a queue.

When the partner logs in, they can view the queue and access the cases but they do not have the option to select the checkbox in the left hand corner to assign themselves a case. Is it possible for Partners to select Cases from a queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in contact with Salesforce Support and it turns out that Community users cannot accept cases from a queue even though they can view the queue (quite silly in my opinion). As a work around I downloaded a free app from the AppExchange called 'Take Ownership of Cases' which displays a 'Take Ownership' button on top of the case record. When it is clicked the partner takes ownership of the case.  It prevents them from going through the process of - 'Change ownership'  - enter new name of Case Owner.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you can edit the user profile for your partner user, under App Permissions, select Transfer Cases. We had the same issue with Leads and found the permission that needed to be turned on under App Permissions when editing the user profile.

Comment: Good to see you identified the proper permission!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. They have the potential to create, read and update leads if given permission to do so. Have you created a permissionset for Partner Community Users that allows them to do that, or else added that permission to their custom Partner Community User profile? If not, once you do, they should be able to do what you're asking.

**Edit**

Go to User > Queue and click on Edit. Add the Users that comprise your Partner Community Users to the Queue either by Role or by a Group (however you're defined them). That should solve your problem assuming you're using the same page layout for them. It sounds they aren't part of the Queue as it's currently defined.

Comment: I have granted the user permission to Create /Read /Edit cases which they can do, but they cannot Accept cases from a queue. (There is no checkboxes or Accept button available for the users in the communities portal)

Comment: Go to User > Queue and click on Edit. Add the Users that consist of your Partner Community Users to the Queue either by Role or by a Group that you've defined. That should solve your problem assuming you're using the same page layout for them. Most likely they aren't part of the Queue as it's currently defined.

Comment: The users are a part of the Queue. They can see the queue in the portal and select the cases in the queue. What they cannot do is, tick the checkbox that normally appears beside the case where they can select and 'Accept.

Comment: Try editing the Page Layout to make certain the checkbox is not read only on their User Profile or clone the Page Layout to create a new one assigned to Users with their Profile where the checkbox is available to them. That would be the next thing that comes to mind to do.

Comment: It is not the page layout of the Case object that is the issue. It is the view section where I cannot see the checkboxes /Accept button.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that because this is happening in your partner community, you may need to edit your assignment rules to make certain a user with a partner community profile can take assignment of a case from the queue.